# Google берет сниппет не оттуда, откуда мне нужно

Tags: google-search, сниппет

Причем по одному запросу все нормально(petrofskybeats catalogue):
[image: petrofskybeats catalogue]

А по другому нет(petr of sky beats):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сайт - petrofskybeats.com

Я так понял, он берет это описание из текста. Кусочек из текста на странице, кусочек из фрейма с плеером. На фрейме поставил тег для отмены индексации, не помогло.

Почему это произошло и как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Можете заполнить мета тег description на нужное описание и в поисковике будет именно оно

Comment: Описание заполнено правильно, можете посмотреть на самом сайте, я для этого его и скинул.

Comment: site:petrofskybeats.com - по такому запросу вы можите посмотреть все проиндексированные запросы, вашего варианта с неправильным описанием не вижу...можите кинуть конкретный запрос по которому такое вылазит?

Comment: запрос - petr of sky beats, поправил стартовый пост. 3я ссылка в ответе гугла.

Comment: странно, первый раз такое вижу, извините но поидее я вам не помогу(

Comment: Вот я сам удивился :)

Comment: Я уже и у сеошника спрашивал... Говорит что тоже первый раз видит...